# VT graph thermodynamics

Tags: physical-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, thermodynamics, everyday-chemistry

If we have one mole monoatomic ideal gas was taken through process AB as shown in the figure then ∆ S is positive and work is also positive but how can we find the value of work and heat absorbed as pressure is changing .k[image]

Comment: From what you learned in middle school algebra, what is the equation for the straight line between points A and B in terms of V and T?  If you solve this equation for T and substitute it into the ideal gas law, what do you get for P in terms of V? What is the equation for the work in terms of P and V?  If you know the work and the change in internal energy, do you know the heat?

Comment: Yes but I forget that

Comment: Do you remember it now, or do you need to go back to your old algebra text book?  This is not really a chemistry question, it's a math question.

Comment: But can you help me

Comment: Can you help yourself? He literally spelt out everything you need to do. Start by finding $p$ in terms of $V$. Google "equation of a straight line through two points" if you need maths help.

Comment: The graph is of volume and temperature no $y= mx+b$  equation is going to help him.

Comment: @A.K., are you saying that you can't use the graph to determine the equation of the straight line V=mT+b, where m is the slope and b is the V intercept.  Or, better yet, as orthocresol indicates, you can't determine the equation using the point-slope version of the equation?

Comment: He's looking for pressure and heat, which are not graphed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the number of moles of ideal gas, you can find the inital and final pressures with the ideal gas law: $PV = nRT$.  For entropy you may first take that $U = \frac{3}{2} nRT$, and that $dU = \delta Q + \delta W$. $ $  $\delta Q $ and $ \delta W$ may be substituted by $\delta Q = T \mathrm{d}S$, and $\delta W = -p\mathrm{d}V$. This should be enough for you to solvew the problem.

Comment: Why you have equate Q = Tds and in this how will we find ds

Comment: You find d$S$ because you know everything else.

Comment: W = -pdV but pressure is changing

Comment: Do it in two steps where you change pressure, then volume and add the two results.